# Best way to realize a polling service

Tags: c#, vb.net, polling

I have a form in a Windows Form application, I need to repeatedly poll a database. I'm here for asking, what is the best way to make this simple form in a poll service, avoiding deadlock and similar issues (I wouldn't use a Windows service)?

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public PollingService(){
        // do some stuff every x seconds
    }
}
```

PS: I'm not asking for a ready-code. I just need to know how to organise this.

Comment: What was wrong with my question? O_o

Comment: "Notification Service" of MS Sql Server is much better than polling the DB. Do you know it?

Comment: Alireza is right, using some kind of realtime notification would be way better than polling, it avoids a great amount of unneccessary overhead.

Comment: YEs, I know but we haven't that type of access to DB server (i.e. we can just query the DB).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this, if you still want to poll. You can use a timer.

example:

```
    private Timer _dbCheckTimer;

    public void InitTimer()
    {
        _dbCheckTimer = new Timer();
        _dbCheckTimer.Elapsed += DBCheckTimer_Elapsed;
        _dbCheckTimer.Interval = 10000; // 10 seconds
        _dbCheckTimer.Start();
    }

    public void DisposeTimer()
    {
        _dbCheckTimer.Dispose();
    }

    void DBCheckTimer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        _dbCheckTimer.Stop();
        try
        {
            // check DB
        }
        finally
        {
            _dbCheckTimer.Start();
        }
    }
```